# Can't change transform.position of Instantiated GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a random world with some trees that get randomly instantiated.

I use the following code to instantiate them:

```
GameObject go = Instantiate(treePrefab);
go.name = "Tree";
go.tag = "Wood";
go.layer = 9;
go.transform.position = new Vector3(y + UnityEngine.Random.Range(-0.5f, 0.5f), heightPos, x + UnityEngine.Random.Range(-0.5f, 0.5f));
go.transform.Rotate(0, UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 360), 0);
```

`x` and `y` are part of a for loop that goes through all positions (like a grid) of my world.

`heightPos` is the current height of the terrain at the specific point (x/y).

My problem is that the prefab ob the trees has the position 0, 0, 0.

Every tree that get's instantiated gets set to 0, 0, 0 too.

I use the exact same code to instantiate rocks, cactus, feathers, car's and many other things, and it works perfect.

but it always fails at the trees.

I've looked through the code and there is no difference to the other objects, except the prefab (of course).

So i think it has to do something with the settings of the prefab.

But my prefab got no animator, it is not static or something.

This is what my tree-Prefab looks like in the inspector:

[image]

and this is what it looks like in scene view:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some some info on where you call the code you showed?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues i just added the whole code. It is inside the Start()-Method of a empty GameObject that is just for creating the world.

Comment: When i instantiate it using this code: GameObject.Instantiate(treeUF1, new Vector3(y + UnityEngine.Random.Range(-0.5f, 0.5f), heightPos, x + UnityEngine.Random.Range(-0.5f, 0.5f)), Quaternion.identity) it works, but i can't change the position afterwards.

Comment: ...hmmm... I didn't mean to make you to post the whole class code. You should provide a [mcve] that any of us can test on our editor and reproduce the wrong behavior.

Comment: Nothing else different about this prefab? Its not parented differently? No other scripts attached? Does it make a difference if you use transform.localPosition instead of transform.position to move it?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues sorry, i'm still learning :)

Comment: @FredrikWiderberg the only thing that is different is that it has a different collider size. localPosition isn't doing a difference.

Comment: If you use a different prefab in this same script, what happens?

Comment: @NathaliaSoragge just tried that, it works fine with a different prefab.

Comment: Not sure what go try next.  Hard to guess when i cant reproduce..

Comment: @FredrikWiderberg i also have no ideas anymore. To reproduce you just need to spawn a tree from the pack "UF Creator LITE" (free in Asset store) and try changing its position via transform.position.

Comment: I downloaded Ultimate Fantasy Creator Lite and tried all three different tree-prefabs, no problems there

Comment: @FredrikWiderberg thanks for testing, hm then it seems like i have another problem... i can't move them.

Comment: This is definitely odd. I can't think of why this is happening.

Comment: What does that ResourceWood script do? It's the only thing I can see in the prefab that could be overwriting the position.

Comment: @NathaliaSoragge RessourceWood doesn't change the position. It just holds information about the amount of wood you gather, when you harvest the tree and what kind of wood you get.

Comment: This is too weird, I have no clue ):

Comment: @AlpakaJoe Are you setting the parent of the instantiated object somewhere? Can you post the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another gameobject and make this instance as a child of that gameobject so even if the instance is always at (0, 0, 0) you can always change the position of the parent object.

Comment: i tried that, but same problem, they still get spawned at 0, 0, 0.

Comment: Maybe something's about the tags, and layers. All trees have the same tag, but other prefabs have different tags. Maybe there is a code that manipulates the position of objects that are tagged as "wood", or something similar. Just check what is different about this prefab that is not the same as other prefabs

Comment: i have four different trees in my game, the other three work fine and have the same tag and layer as the one, who is not working.